# How to redirect to specific URL?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route for tenants name like that:

```
example.test/TenantNameHere
```

And I want to make the default of my domain start with the word "site":

```
example.test/site
```

My code:

```
Route::prefix('{tenantName}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($tenantName) {
        return "{$tenantName}";
    });
});


Route::prefix('site')->group(function () {
    Route::get('price', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});

Route::redirect('/', 'site', 301);
```

The problem that I'm facing with this code now is when I open the domain it redirects me to `tenantName` route, not to the home page that I made!

How can spreate the route of `site` from `TenantName` ?

Comment: You should have a look at the docs. I believe that will point you in the right direction. Alternatively, look for online examples of routes in Laravel. There are plenty. Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#redirect-routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to register your absolute path ('site') first, and "wildcards" routes after, because everything you put in url line now hit the first tenantName route

try this (reverse the order):

```
Route::redirect('/', '/site', 301);

Route::prefix('site')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});

Route::prefix('{tenantName}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($tenantName) {
        return "{$tenantName}";
    });
});
```

also change "/site/price" path to "/site", so redirect will find correct route

Comment: Yes, that's right and when I visit "site/price" it worked but how can make the path ('site') the default of the home page of my domain without hit the tenant name!?

Comment: just edit my answer, don't know if I understand well, but this should work, try or give me more details please :)